# Adding a second change event to existing Worksheet Change code

Tags: excel, vba

I have put together the code below and it works as intended. I currently have a formula that I am running in rows 2:28 on column Q but I want to convert this to a second change event. I have researched and found the "If Not Intersect" code, but do not know how to integrate it properly to my code and make it functional. Please help.

Here is the original code (below that is the formula I am trying to integrate into the change event):

```vb
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim DestWH As String
    Dim DWHRowNum As Long
    Dim dt As Date
    
    DWHRowNum = 2
    dt = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Do Until Cells(DWHRowNum, 2).Value = ""
        Select Case Cells(DWHRowNum, 6).Value
            Case Is = "ABQ1"
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
            Case Is = "BFI4"
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt + 1
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "04:30"
            Case Is = "CLE2"
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
            Case Is = "DEN3"
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
            Case Is = "DEN4"
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt + 1
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "04:30"
            Case Is = "GEG1"
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
            Case Is = "LIT1"
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
            Case Is = "ORD5"
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
            Case Is = "ORF3"
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
            Case Is = "PAE2"
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
            Case Is = "PCW1"
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
            Case Is = "PDX9"
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt + 1
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "04:30"
            Case Is = "SLC1"
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
           Case Is = "SMF1"
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt + 1
                Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "04:30"
        End Select
        DWHRowNum = DWHRowNum + 1
    Loop
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    End Sub
```

Formula (This formula resides in column Q2:Q28):

```
=IF(G2="","",IF(AND(M2="",N2>G2),"Future","Current"))
```

Columns G and N are dates

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry, to have the formula in column Q run automatically when a date is input by the user into one of the cells in column N2:N28.

Comment: Excel will automatically update the result of formulas after users inputting. Why do u need Change event?

Comment: I use other code that "archives" all the data and clears the contents for the next shift to use. I don't want to skip any columns and I don't want the formulas deleted. This was the better solution. Not necessarily the easiest though.

Comment: There's no `Case Else` in your code to clear any existing values from G and H in the event one of the row's F value does match any of your terms.  Also, you `Dim dt As Date` but then do `dt = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyy")` which would raise an error.  Does this code actually run as-posted?

Comment: The "yyy" was not throwing an error, just giving a wrong date. I did fix that already (apparently forgot to paste the corrected code here ;))

Comment: The code that clears is part of a different sub that runs from a button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: to have the formula in column Q run automatically when a date is input by the user into one of the cells in column N2:N28

- Simplify `Case` clause in your code.
- Add the 2nd part to apply a formula on Q2:Q28

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim DestWH As String
    Dim DWHRowNum As Long
    Dim toDay As String, nextDay As String
    DWHRowNum = 2
    toDay = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    nextDay = Format(Date + 1, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Do Until Cells(DWHRowNum, 2).Value = ""
        Select Case Cells(DWHRowNum, 6).Value
        Case "ABQ1", "CLE2", "DEN3", "GEG1", "LIT1", "ORD5", "ORF3", "PAE2", "PCW1", "SLC1"
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = toDay
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
        Case "BFI4", "DEN4", "PDX9", "SMF1"
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = nextDay
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "04:30"
        End Select
        DWHRowNum = DWHRowNum + 1
    Loop
    ' ** Update
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("N2:N28")) Is Nothing Then
                If Len(.Value) > 0 And IsDate(.Value) Then
                    If Not Me.Range("Q2").HasFormula Then
                        Me.Range("Q2:Q28").Formula = "=IF(G2="""","""",IF(AND(M2="""",N2>G2),""Future"",""Current""))"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you. I did a quick edit to place the formula in the correct column. It should run in column Q. {If Not Me.Range("Q2").HasFormula Then
                        Me.Range("Q2:Q28").Formula = "=IF(G2="""","""",IF(AND(M2="""",N2>G2),""Future"",""Current""))"}

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim rw As Range, dt, tm, vn, vm, vg
    
    On Error GoTo haveError 'so not to leave events turned off...
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Set rw = Me.Rows(2) 'start with row2
    Do While Len(rw.Columns("B").Value) > 0
        Debug.Print rw.Row
        Select Case rw.Columns("F").Value
            'you can list multiple values in the same `Case`
            Case "ABQ1", "CLE2", "DEN3", "GEG1", "LIT1", _
                         "ORF3", "PAE2", "PCW1", "SLC1"
                dt = Date
                tm = "17:00"
            Case "BFI4", "DEN4", "PDX9", "SMF1"
                dt = dt + 1
                tm = "04:30"
            Case Else
                dt = Empty 'no match: clear variables
                tm = Empty
        End Select
        
        'now figure out what to do with Cols G, H and Q
        If Len(tm) > 0 Then 'any match above?
            rw.Columns("G").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
            rw.Columns("G").Value = dt
            rw.Columns("H").Value = tm
            
            vm = rw.Columns("M").Value
            vn = rw.Columns("N").Value
            vg = rw.Columns("G").Value
            rw.Columns("Q").Value = IIf(Len(vm) = 0 And vn > vg, "Future", "Current")
        Else
            'clear G, H and Q
            'note range is *relative* to `rw`
            rw.Range("G1,H1,Q1").ClearContents
        End If
        
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1) 'next row down
    Loop
haveError:
    If Err.Number > 0 Then Debug.Print Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```